# coffeescript syntax error "unexpected REGEX"

Tags: syntax, coffeescript, syntax-error

I'm trying to convert jquery into coffeescript but I'm getting syntax error

```
SyntaxError: unexpected REGEX
```

This is my code:

```
container = document.querySelector('#style-container');
msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's not CoffeeScript.  This is CoffeeScript:

```
container = document.querySelector "#style-container" 
msnry = new Masonry(container,
  columnWidth: 200
  itemSelector: ".item"
)
```

You can convert JavaScript to CoffeeScript using [this tool](http://js2cs.nodejitsu.com/).

The specific error is referring to the comment tag.  `//` doesn't mean a comment in CoffeeScript, so it falls back to an empty regular expression.  A more useful regular expression would be `/[0-9]+/`, however the contents are optional in CoffeeScript.

```
// this is a JS comment
# this is a CS comment
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is you are using `//` for a comment instead of `#`.

In addition to that, you example still looks more like JavaScript than CoffeeScript, but that's the specific error you are getting. See also http://js2coffee.org/

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript comments start with `#`, instead of `//`.  As noted above the `//` is used for a blank regex.  When learning CoffeeScript, I recommend http://coffeescript.org/ and the Try CoffeeScript tool, so that you can see the JavaScript that your CoffeeScript would give rise to.